# guvectorize Not resolving types in nopython mode

Tags: python, vectorization, jit, numba

I'm struggling with a numba error
`Untyped global name 'is_a_subset': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.np.ufunc.gufunc.GUFunc'>`
This usually means I have fumbled and used a method that isn't supported by numba. The following code fails.

```
@guvectorize("(n),(n)->(n)",nopython=True)
def is_a_subset(x,y,out):
    out[:]=np.array([item in x for item in y])

@njit()
def test(x,y,z):
    is_a_subset(x,y,z)
    return z.mean()

x=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
y=np.array([[3,6,1],[1,2,3]])
z = np.empty_like(x)
test(x,y,z)
```

However removing njit on the test function makes everything work.

```
def test(x,y,z):
    is_a_subset(x,y,z)
    return z.mean()
```

Why is numba struggling to resolve types when in no-python mode?
I had also tried without different results

```
@guvectorize(["f8[:],f8[:],f8[:]"],"(n),(n)->(n)",nopython=True)
def is_a_subset(x,y,out):
    out[:]=np.array([item in x for item in y])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Numba 0.53.1 and can replicate this error. This [blog](https://labs.quansight.org/blog/2021/02/enhancements-to-numba-guvectorize-decorator/) on the dynamic dispatch update to `guvectorize` in Numba 0.53 mentions this at the end (emphasis added):

> In the future we would like to bring the `@guvectorize` capabilities closer to the `@vectorize` ones. For instance, *currently it is not possible to call a guvectorize function from a jitted (`@jit`) function.*

There is a similar [open issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5720) with `vectorize`, but it demonstrates that `@vectorize` functions can be called in `@jit` functions, just that it's restricted to the default `target = "cpu"`.

Comment: any idea how to vectorize this function?

Comment: Until the Numba devs work this stuff out (and it might be a while), I would just design small `@njit`, `@vectorize`, or `@guvectorize` functions that get called in 1 normal Python function that acts like the glue, just like your undecorated `test`. When you put all the loops and vectorizing into NumPy or Numba, there's almost nothing left to optimize in the glue function.