# using @guvectorize inside @jit in numba produces error

Tags: python, numba

Adopting the example ([link](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator)) from the documentation, the code:

```py
from numba import guvectorize, int64

@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64, int64[:])], '(n),()->(n)')
def g(x, y, res):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i] = x[i] + y
        
@njit
def fun():
    a = np.arange(5)
    return g(a, 2)

fun()
```

Produces error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'g': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>

File "<ipython-input-37-02f67c08c51f>", line 4:
def fun():
    <source elided>
    a = np.arange(5)
    return g(a, 2)
    ^
```

However, if you comment out the decoration with `@njit`, `fun()` returns correctly.

So, the standalone `@guvectorize`-d function works fine, but doesn't work when it is used inside a function decorated with `@njit`.

*Is this expected behaviour? If not, do you have any ideas about how it can be fixed?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154359/guvectorize-not-resolving-types-in-nopython-mode). If you are not constrained to use a `guvectorized` function, you have several possible workarounds: one can be converting your `guvectorized` function to a `njit` one, which will work without problems inside another `njit` function.